# How to reduce oscillations in this active filter circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, filter, active-filter

I am trying to build an active filter that takes a tail pulse (~100 ns rise, 100 us fall) from a preamp and shapes it into a Gaussian to be read in by an ADC. I've come as far as getting a good approximation of a Gaussian, but there is a trailing oscillation that I can't get rid of when tinkering with component values.

I'd like to keep the filter design limited to two opamps if possible. Any suggestions on component values to remove the oscillations?

[image]

Comment: "*I've come as far as getting a good approximation of a Gaussian*" -- how you achieved that: hammering, or calculations? I'm asking because there is such a thing as Gaussian filter in classical filter design.

Comment: AC simulations are great for designing filters. Could you attach an AC voltage source to the input of the filter chain and post the frequency response curves after each individual filter?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I hammered this out. No calculations. In my searching for Gaussian filters, I've mostly come across Sallen-Key topologies.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280786/why-doesnt-a-sallen-key-butterworth-filter-ring

Comment: Try selecting values for a Bessel response.

Answer (score 5):

Sallen-Key is the topology, Gaussian is the name of the filter design. Just to be clear, Gaussian filters are non-causal by design, which is why the filters that you'll meet in the wild are approximations.

They start with the definition for the Gaussian filter, which is a *temporal* filter meant to provide zero-overshoot, and whose frequency domain response is a Gaussian bell:

$$|H(j\omega)|^2=\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma \omega^2} \tag{1}$$

Where \$\sigma\$ is a correction factor, usually \$\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\$ to provide \$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ corner frequency. And to convert this to a transfer function you use the MacLaurin series:

$$\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma\omega^2}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^k\dfrac{\sigma}{k!}\omega^{2k}} \tag{2}$$

Instead of \$\infty\$, the order, \$N\$, is used, so you can guess that the terms will be truncated and, the lower the order, the worse the approximation. The next step is finding out the roots and then using those to build the filter, for whatever topology you wish.

Looking at your circuit, I see either a highpass, or a differentiator (`C1, R1`), feeding a 2nd order lowpass, with an extra RC lowpass (`R6, C3`). Are you looking for a 3rd order, or a 2nd order? My suggestion would be to go either for a 4th or a 5th order since, `U2` is wasted as a gain only filter but, you can use that as a filter with gain. Also, given the high frequency content I'd recommend usig a multiple-feedback topology because Sallen-Key have an Achille's heel: the reactance of the feedback capacitor (`C2` in your schematic) will get lower and lower with increasing frequency -- most probably not something you're looking for.

Having said these, I'll continue with a 4th order and then mention the possibility of a 5th but, since you know better what you want, if that's not what you're looking for then please let me know.

A 4th order has this series (I'll use \$\exp()\$ for better reading):

$$\exp\left(-\dfrac{\omega^2}{\ln(2)}\right)=1-\dfrac{\omega^2}{\ln(2)}+\dfrac{\omega^4}{2\ln(2)^2}-\dfrac{\omega^6}{6\ln(2)^3}+\dfrac{\omega^8}{24\ln(2)^4} \tag{3}$$

The roots are complex conjugate, both LHS and RHS:

```
  -0.983313870822120 + 0.882820027033557i
  -0.983313870822120 - 0.882820027033557i
   0.983313870822118 + 0.882820027033556i
   0.983313870822118 - 0.882820027033556i
  -1.128409242515200 + 0.273034843735165i
  -1.128409242515200 - 0.273034843735165i
   1.128409242515202 + 0.273034843735164i
   1.128409242515202 - 0.273034843735164i
```

Select the LHS roots to construct the transfer function:

$$\begin{align}
H_4(s)&=\prod_{k=1}^4\left(\dfrac{|p_k|}{s-p_k}\right) \\
{}&=\dfrac{2.3537}{(s^2+1.9666s+1.7463)(s^2+2.2568s+1.3479)} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

I've split the 4th order into two 2nd order sections, ready to be used with just about any filter design software. One I found very reliable is [this site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Fkeisan.htm). Again, I'd recommend the multiple-feedback topology but, it's up to you.

In case you need a 5th order, the roots are:

```
  -1.002131999453590 + 1.081891709016792i
  -1.002131999453590 - 1.081891709016792i
   1.002131999453590 + 1.081891709016792i
   1.002131999453590 - 1.081891709016792i
  -1.179450767050313 + 0.497750815923211i
  -1.179450767050313 - 0.497750815923211i
   1.179450767050314 + 0.497750815923213i
   1.179450767050314 - 0.497750815923213i
  -1.229423311936897 +                 0i
   1.229423311936892 +                 0i
```

And the transfer function:

$$H_5(s)=\dfrac{4.3818}{(s+1.2294)(s^2+2.0043s+2.1748)(s^2+2.3589s+1.6389)} \tag{5}$$

The 1st order can be implemented as a simple RC attached to the chain, either at the end or at the beginning but, I'd recommend for the beginning. Be sure to make the elements about 10x smaller than the load, so that they don't influence each other through the loading effect (e.g. if the equivalent load is 10 kΩ then make the equivalent output impedance at most 1 kΩ).

Here's a test for the 4th order (I'll leave it up to you for the 5th). The Q for each stage are `0.67196` and `0.51444` (if you intend to use the link I provided). The frequency response vs the mathematical formula (shown at linear scale since the exponential has infinite attenuation):

[image: freq]

And the time domain response for a 1 μs pulse with 100 ns rise/fall times (I see a gain of 3 so that's what I used):

[image: time]

You may be a bit disappointed by the asymmetrical response but, remember: the mathematical formula has zero phase, non-causal, physically impossible. What you see is an *approximation*. Still, is has (almost) zero over-/under-shoot.

---

[edit]

For the sake of proving what I said earlier about the Sallen-Key topology, here's how the same 4th order Gaussian filter looks like when the MFB is compared with the SK:

[image: SK vs MFB, freq]

Notice how the rolloff starts even earlier for the blue trace (hint: it's not the MFB) and how there is a peaking which is cut short, making it look like a flimsily damped pole? That's because of the unwanted zero introduced by the feedback capacitor, and the limited GBW of the opamp (if it had been in the hundreds of MHz then you would have seen a rising slope, instead). The filters were calculated for a 1 MHz corner frequency yet, the SK already has less than -10 dB there.

And this is how the time domain looks like for the same input as above, with the difference that its width is swept from 200 ns to 1 μs, in steps of 200 ns:

[image: MFB vs SK, time]

I hope you can read the values. if not, here's the BOM, as given by LTspice:

```
--- Bill of Materials ---

Ref.    Mfg.    Part No.    Description
C1  --  --  capacitor, 56pF
C2  --  --  capacitor, 9.1pF
C3  --  --  capacitor, 75pF
C4  --  --  capacitor, 7.5pF
C5  --  --  capacitor, 6.8pF
C6  --  --  capacitor, 6.8pF
C7  --  --  capacitor, 6.8pF
C8  --  --  capacitor, 6.8pF
R1  --  --  resistor, 2.67K
R2  --  --  resistor, 10.7K
R3  --  --  resistor, 4.64K
R4  --  --  resistor, 2.61K
R5  --  --  resistor, 9.76K
R6  --  --  resistor, 4.53K
R7  --  --  resistor, 18.2K
R8  --  --  resistor, 30.1K
R9  --  --  resistor, 13K
R10 --  --  resistor, 10K
R11 --  --  resistor, 13.7K
R12 --  --  resistor, 42.2K
R13 --  --  resistor, 10K
R14 --  --  resistor, 13.7K
U1  Analog Devices  ADA4637 integrated circuit
U2  Analog Devices  ADA4637 integrated circuit
U3  Analog Devices  ADA4637 integrated circuit
U4  Analog Devices  ADA4637 integrated circuit
```

Comment: Now I see that you used a 180 mV pulse with 100 *micro*seconds fall time, more like a step. However, I don't know where those voltages come from since you haven't labeled your nodes. It doesn't matter: the response needs to have as little overshoot as possible so that's what a Gaussian filter is for.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a comparison with the SK topology.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this answer. Very well presented and I actually understand the filter a little better.

Comment: This filter does not produce a gaussian pulse given a 10ns rise and 100us fall input pulse. The output begins as a gaussian, but does not fall on the tail end. How can the circuit be modified to work properly?

Comment: @earl A Gaussian pulse is symmetric. What you're asking for is an *asymmetric* pulse, therefore you cannot talk about a "Gaussian pulse". What you did was you've added the `C1, R1` group as a lowpass (or differentiator), which is then lowpass filtered. I've mentioned this in my answer. You've probably removed that group (and, thus, its functionality).

Comment: @a concerned citizen https://www.cremat.com/CR-200-R2.1.pdf

Comment: @earl If you meant to confirm what I said, you've achieved it. Was there something in particular you wished to show?

Comment: Try your simulation again but with the input pulse rise time and fall time being 10n and 100u respectively. It does not produce a symmetric gaussian at the output.

Comment: @earl Did you add the `C1, R1` filter as I *keep mentioning* and you seem to keep on ignoring? Do you see it anywhere in the schematic I posted? Can you try to read everything, and not just skim over, before pointing the finger? Let me help you, at least with a quote from my last comment: "*You've probably removed that group (and, thus,* ***its functionality*** *)*". And, in case you're still wondering why that is, it's because the highpass/differentiator acts as a converter, transforming the slow falling edge to a sharp(er) one. It's even in the pdf you so graciously linked.